# Unity 2D: My "Melee" Animation Repeat Twice

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to access the "melee" animation just pressing the key "C", it works but it repeats twice. Here's part of my code:

```
bool melee = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C);

if (melee) 
{           
    _animator.SetTrigger("melee");
}
```

Comment: When is this code being called? You need to provide more information to give context.

Comment: It is called in the update function.

Comment: Try `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C)` instead. `Input.GetKey()` returns true every frame the key is held down.